# Using Array.fill() and Array.splice() together doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

[while solving this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen), I had to use something like the following lines of code where the line right after `for loop` didn't work!

```js
function staircase(n) {
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
       const e = Array(n).fill(' ').splice(n - i, i, ...Array(i).fill('#'));
       console.log(e.join(''))
    }
}
```

But, the following did!

```js
function staircase(n) {
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
       const e = Array(n).fill(' ');
       e.splice(n - i, i, ...Array(i).fill('#'));
       console.log(e.join(''))
    }
}
```

I wonder, why using splice() with fill() in one line didn't work!

Comment: Splice returns *An array containing the deleted elements.*

Comment: @anttud not really. splice is supposed to return the removed elements as array by spec.

Comment: WOWI Why didn't I notice this! Thanks!

Comment: None of the above comments actually explain why it didn't work in one line. Because looking at the code, it seems that it should from how OP wrote it.

Comment: @mardubbles sure it does. The first example assigns the removed elements to `e`. The second assigns an array of `n` elements to `e` then mutates that array

Comment: Ahh I see your point @Phil, on `e.splice` return value not being assigned.

Answer (score 2):

As has been explained in the comments:

```js
const e = Array(n).fill(' ').splice(n - i, i, ...Array(i).fill('#'));
```

This assigns the result of `splice` to `e`.

```
const e = Array(n).fill(' ');
e.splice(n - i, i, ...Array(i).fill('#'));
```

This assigns the result of the first `fill` to `e`, and then splice acts upon `e`.